# mysql query miss some rows occasionally

Tags: mysql

I'm having this problem, here is my sql statements:

```
select * from tb1 where id > the_max_read order by id
```

The table **tb1** is to monitor some other tables' changes, so it keeps growing.
Variable **the_max_read** is the max id that program already read.
I'm running this sql via C++ and using mysql's mysql_query function, and save result with mysql_store_result.
DB engine is **innodb**.

The problem is that it miss some rows sometime, not always but keep happening.

For example, say I have this table:

```
|   -- id | -- name|  
| 834370  |  name1 |  
| 834371  |  name2 |  
| 834372  |  name3 |  
| 834373  |  name4 |  
| 834374  |  name5 |  
| 834375  |  name6 |
```

and **the_max_read=834371**, when run the above sql, the result **only contains 834374 and 834375**.

Though this table may be inserted some new rows by other programs, but I still cannot understand why it just miss some rows, it's almost the simplest sql.

Comment: What are your locking settings? Especially autocommit and isolation level. I find it not surprising that rows that are added by different transactions are not visible directly.

Comment: @flowit I have tried to keep Id in order in my program, if the minimum id read is not current max_read+1, I'll read again and will try for 30 seconds until replace the current max_id. Do you think some transaction could run over 30s to commit? All MySQL setting is default.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be a transaction issue, where you read before some of the transactions are committed.

Try read uncommitted data: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-transaction.html

e.g.

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
select * from tb1 where id > the_max_read order by id;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there any chance that I may read some dirty data？what should I do to keep my data correct?

Comment: In my understanding of your example, at the point when you read 834371,  the records 834373  and 834372 are "dirty data" (not yet committed). Your expectation though is to see the records in your output. But the records could still get rolled back. In my view your current situation is correct, but if you wish to see the records when you do the read, then you will be reading uncommitted data

Comment: I am pretty sure 834373 and 834374 aren't rolled back, I have this db now and I can see they are just there. I'm thinking maybe the transaction  commit 834373 and 834734 really costs over 30sec. That two rows are inserted by triggers of tables I want to monitor. Maybe some operations to those tables run too slow. I'm a little bit desperate now, so clueless.

Comment: Sorry the point I was trying to make is that at that point in time when the_max_read=834371 then the transactions are not yet committed. Perhaps optimize the other operations as you suggest.